# Trying to find a "soft clamp" function (a bit differenct characterstics from Smoothstep)

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a function to use as a kind of "soft clamp" for my procedural animation.

Current and desired soft clamp:

[image]

Currently I use a simple $$y = \min(y_\max, x),$$ the purple line in the diagram. That results in the "corner" at $y_\max$, which is really jarring in animation. I would like something like the orange line. The Smoothstep function is not what I need, because as you can see from the orange line, I would like the new soft clamp function to be similar to $y=x$ for most of the range below $y_\max$, and to approach $y_\max$ asymptotically. So far none of the analytical functions I tried look like that; I would really appreciate some helpful ideas about how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try

$$g(x)=\min\left(x,\phi\left(x-\frac{y_{\max}}{2}\right)\right)$$

Where
$$\phi(x)=\frac{y_{\text{max}}}{1+\exp\left(-\frac{4}{y_\max}x\right)}$$

### **[PLOT](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sdim3jsotl)**

Comment: Thanks so much, that's perfect!

Comment: @Krawlak You can mark the answer as accepted to resolve this topic.